# How to run db migration script in the production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use `RAILS_ENV=production` and `rake db:migrate`,is there any way to pass argument as a command line parameter instead.

Comment: What difference will it make (comparing to what you have now)?

Comment: if the version parameter is what you want, and you use heroku, you can  rollback to previous versions of your application, rewrite your migrations from code, and rerun them. Maybe there are other solutions as well :-?

Comment: which version you are working on ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
   rake db:migrate:status RAILS_ENV=production    # Display status of migrations


rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=my_version
Or you can go up or down from a specific version:

db:migrate:up VERSION=my_version
db:migrate:down VERSION=my_version
```

It's all just the examples and you need to tell what type of argument u need to pass.